# Django : Create More Than One Tables with Same Model Schema

Tags: django, factory

I have a Django model from which I need to derive many tables. Something like a factory.
The schema of all tables is same but the table name is different.
e.g.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'mytable'
```

I need that in database, I have tables mytable01, mytable02, mytable03 ...

What is the best way to do this in models.py

Comment: What is the use case ? See if you can avoid generating tables this way..

Comment: That won't be possible. Is there to achieve this with given constraint.

Comment: Are you building a django application or a script that builds a database?

Comment: @JohnMee Its a django application

Comment: Rethink your architecture as this approach is certain to turn into a maintenance nightmare.  If all the models are the same then there is no reason the subclass approach won't work.  You seem fixated on generating lots of tables, but haven't (yet) explained why that is a necessary part of the solution.

Comment: I am having a nested set in each model. So schema never changes. However each table generated has different target hierarchies to store.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can sublcass a single abstract model.

```
# No table, since abstract = True
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False)

# Table name "myapp_submodel"
class SubModel(BaseModel):
    pass

# Table name "myapp_anothersubmodel"
class AnotherSubModel(BaseModel):
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False)
```

More info at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes

Comment: Can we add a method with a parameter (name to be added to the table) that generates tables

Comment: Yes, just add the table name to each sub model `class Meta: db_table = 'tablename'` and then run `manage.py syncdb`